# How to detect changes on iframe

Tags: html

I have this iframe. It's height is dynamic. on load it's height is reset so I don't see the scroll bar on the right. But my problem is when the size of elements change in the iframe, I do not know how to detect those changes, I tried giving onchange attribute to HTML to set the height again, but onchange didn't fire. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to set the on change to the viewport, not HTML.  When you resize the window, it doesn't change the HTML.

Comment: I tried using onchange to iframe, didn't fire either. Apparently onchange fires only with inputs.